# Order strings in mm-yyyy format by date order

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table1 with nvachar field name monthyear

```
01-2021
02-2021
03-2021
04-2020
04-2021
05-2020
```

My goal to get data in order by mm-yyyy so it look like this

```
01-2021
02-2021
03-2021
04-2021
04-2020
05-2020
```

My query

```
With TempTable AS (
      select monthyear, try_convert(datetime, monthyear) as SomeDate
      from table1
      
     )
Select * 
from TempTable
```

And I got return 'someday' null. Not sure what was wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Ideally, don't store date and time values as a string; there are several date( and time) data types to choose from, and all of them are infinitely better choices.

Comment: If you want to store a month/year and still use date order, use `yyyy-MM`. You need to do the same if you want to filter by a period, eg `where monthyear between '2021-01' and '2021-03'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a format.  Try this:

```
try_convert(date, '01-' + year_month, 103)
```

Comment: Yes, I can add date on it. It's working fine. Well, way to go.

Comment: @user13570703 look again. your desired result sorts by year first (desc), then month (asc)